# Backslash replace in a java path

Tags: java

I've got this path :

```
 /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

And I need it for a `options.setBinary`. The problem is that I've got an error in my java due to the backslash, but that's my path!

I also try to use this :

```
 String newString = text.replace(...);
```

But my command needs a path and sends error if I add new string

```
 options.setBinary(" /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome ");
```

What can I do ?

Comment: you have a path with both forward slash and backslash ?

Comment: Yes, when i want to run the app in my terminal, that's the path i have. Moreover, it's what i need to use as sayed here : https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
 options.setBinary(new File("/Applications/Google/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google/Chrome"));
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

As @Tom and @Erwin Bolwidt commented bellow path should change as this (for mac os):

```
options.setBinary(new File("/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome"));
```

Comment: I'm not the voter, but why do you change OPs file path? His app name is `Google Chrome.app` and you change it to `Chrome.app` in the `Google` sub-directory.

Comment: Already try to change names, didn't work ! But the chalitha way works

Comment: @Mxfrd do you mean that you no longer get compile errors, or does the code actually work and is able to open the file? How can both chalitha en ctst's answers work for you?

Comment: @Mxfrd I mean: I also have a Mac, and your original path with the backslashes exists when I do a "ls <path>" on it in Terminal, but the one from chalitha with the slashes between "Google" and "Chrome" doesn't work, it gives the error `ls: /Applications/Google/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google/Chrome: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your path is saved as String:

It's because of your `\`. Try replacing it with `\\`, and it should work.